# Java GUI Issue (Layout Manager)

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe, layout-manager

I've just started using Java Layout manager, it's been pretty difficult to get the GUI to behave as desired, so far:

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

    public class ex1 extends JFrame {

    private javax.swing.JButton AddBtn,perviousBtn,NextBtn;
    private javax.swing.JLabel LatLabel, LongLabel, EvlLabel;
    private javax.swing.JTextField LatText,LongText,EvlText;

    String columns[] = { "ID", "Name", "Age", "Gender" };
    Object data[][] = { { "0", "Tom", new Integer(20), "Male" },
            { "1", "Tina", new Integer(18), "Female" },
            { "2", "Raj", new Integer(19), "Male" },
            { "3", "Tina", new Integer(18), "Female" },
            { "4", "Raj", new Integer(19), "Male" },
            { "5", "Tina", new Integer(18), "Female" },
            { "6", "Raj", new Integer(19), "Male" },
            { "7", "Tina", new Integer(18), "Female" },
            { "8", "Raj", new Integer(19), "Male" },
            { "9", "Tina", new Integer(18), "Female" },
            { "10", "Raj", new Integer(19), "Male" }
    };

    public void addComponentsToPane(final Container pane) {

        JPanel compsToExperiment = new JPanel();
        GridLayout experimentLayout = new GridLayout(3, 3);
        compsToExperiment.setLayout(experimentLayout);
        JPanel Table = new JPanel();
        Table.setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 1));
        JPanel nav = new JPanel();
        nav.setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 3));

        LatLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel("Latitude: ");
        LongLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel("Longitude: ");
        EvlLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel("Elevation: ");
        LatText = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        LongText = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        EvlText = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        AddBtn = new javax.swing.JButton("Add");
        perviousBtn = new javax.swing.JButton("Next");
        NextBtn = new javax.swing.JButton("pervious");

        // perviousBtn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(60, 60));

        compsToExperiment.add(LatLabel);
        compsToExperiment.add(LongLabel);
        compsToExperiment.add(EvlLabel);

        compsToExperiment.add(LatText);
        compsToExperiment.add(LongText);
        compsToExperiment.add(EvlText);
        compsToExperiment.add(AddBtn);

        // jButton1.addActionListener((ActionListener) this);
        // this.add(jButton1);

        JTable table = new JTable(data, columns);
        Table.add(table.getTableHeader());
        Table.add(table);

        nav.add(NextBtn);
        nav.add(perviousBtn);

        pane.add(compsToExperiment, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        pane.add(nav, BorderLayout.EAST);
        pane.add(Table, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it. For thread safety, this method is invoked
     * from the event dispatch thread.
     */

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {

        ex1 frame = new ex1();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.addComponentsToPane(frame.getContentPane());
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        //frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {    
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                  "javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        /* Turn off metal's use of bold fonts */
        UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);

        // Schedule a job for the event dispatch thread:
        // creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });    
    }    
}
```

Also I'm having issue to get table to display all the entry, it will only show the first 3 entries. Can you please help me to get the GUI tidy and with table issue.

Comment: `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
"javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel"..`  Please don't set a PLAF in example code unless the question is about PLAFs or only occurs due to PLAFs.  Also, that *is* the default, and there are better ways to get the `String`..

Comment: Consider _autoboxing_, mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12885249/230513).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at these lines:

```
    JPanel Table = new JPanel();
    Table.setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 1));
```

You should read the documentation on GridLayout carefully to use it in your code especially if you are using several layouts just like you do in your code. I suggest you design your components and their layouts on a scratch paper before you attempt to code them. Here, I changed your `Table`'s layout's parameters to this:

```
    Table.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
```

And it displayed all the data entries. Here is what API says on `GridLayout`:

```
public GridLayout(int rows, int cols)
```

*Creates a grid layout with the specified number of rows and columns. All components in the layout are given equal size. 
**One, but not both, of rows and cols can be zero**, which means that **any number of objects can be placed in a row** or in a column.*