# How to hide Mac/OSX Drag and Drop JTable selection frame

Tags: java, macos, swing, jtable, drag-and-drop

When performing a drag and drop on a JTable there is an outline of the selected cell (selection frame) that appears while dragging. How can I override that behavior and not show anything but perhaps a special cursor?

Running the following code in Windows and OSX shows the behavior I'd like to override!

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.dnd.DnDConstants;
import java.awt.dnd.DragGestureEvent;
import java.awt.dnd.DragGestureListener;
import java.awt.dnd.DragSource;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;

public class GestureTest
    extends
        JFrame
    implements
        DragGestureListener {

    private final DragSource ds;
    private final JTable jl;
    private static final Object[][] ITEMS = { { "Java" }, { "C" }, { "C++" }, { "Lisp" },
        { "Perl" }, { "Python" } };

    public GestureTest() {
        super("Gesture Test");
        setSize(200, 150);
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(final WindowEvent we) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        jl = new JTable(ITEMS, new Object[] { "Langs" });
        jl.setDragEnabled(true);
        jl.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(jl), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        ds = new DragSource();
        // final DragGestureRecognizer dgr =
        ds.createDefaultDragGestureRecognizer(
            jl, DnDConstants.ACTION_MOVE, this);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void dragGestureRecognized(final DragGestureEvent dge) {
        System.out.print("dragGestureRecognized");
    }

    public static void main(final String args[]) {
        new GestureTest();
    }

}
```

Comment: A Screenshot of the problem might help

Comment: @NickRippe: I added a screenshot [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12885249/230513); I don't see a way to change it without digging into the Cocoa/Java framework.

Comment: I'd agree with trashgod, I think this is a OS specific issue...The other question is, how are you performing the d'n'd operation?  Via the transferable API or via the core d'n'd API?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, although you will have to write a little bit more of the dnd handling yourself.

First disable JTable's own dnd handling: `jl.setDragEnabled(false);`

Then you can use the following code for the `dragGestureRecognized` method to call `startDrag` yourself.

The important bit is the `empty` image. Using `null` here will cause the OS to display an OS specific image (none for Windows, a grey box for OS X), explicitly setting an image here will cause that image to be displayed instead (an empty 1x1 pixel image in our case).

```java
@Override
public void dragGestureRecognized(final DragGestureEvent dge) {
    System.out.print("dragGestureRecognized");

    Transferable transferable = new Transferable() {
        @Override
        public boolean isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor flavor) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors() {
            return new DataFlavor[] { DataFlavor.stringFlavor };
        }

        @Override
        public Object getTransferData(DataFlavor flavor) throws UnsupportedFlavorException, IOException {
            return "Hello world!";
        }
    };
    BufferedImage empty = new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    dge.startDrag(null, empty, new Point(), transferable, null);
}
```