# Error with AWTView draggingEnded

Tags: java, macos, swing, drag-and-drop

I have a problem when I drag & drop in eclipse with swing in mac OS X.  Sometimes when I drag my object, the application freezes and crashes.

Tested with Java version: 1.7.0_51, 1.6.0_65 and 1.8.0
and Mac OS X: 10.7.5 and 10.9.1

[Some people have already this problem 2 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12881600/drag-and-drop-with-jtable-on-mac-os-x)

```
2014-02-11 10:45:16.982 java[716:707] -[AWTView draggingEnded:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fbc6d84a1e0
2014-02-11 10:45:17.017 java[716:707] -[AWTView draggingEnded:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fbc6d84a1e0
2014-02-11 10:45:17.096 java[716:707] (
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff90648f56 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff93f7dd5e objc_exception_throw + 43
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff906d51be -[NSObject doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 190
3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff90635fa4 ___forwarding___ + 756
4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff90635c38 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 232
5   liblwawt.dylib                      0x000000011754aec2 -[AWTView draggingEnded:] + 136
6   AppKit                              0x00007fff8cfe0f48 NSCoreDragCompletionProc + 497
7   HIServices                          0x00007fff93d9ecc8 DoTrackingMessage + 448
8   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff905d5666 __CFDictionaryApplyFunction_block_invoke_1 + 22
9   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff905b7121 CFBasicHashApply + 113
10  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff905d5644 CFDictionaryApplyFunction + 212
11  HIServices                          0x00007fff93da2098 CoreDragStartDragging + 915
12  AppKit                              0x00007fff8cfe06c0 -[NSCoreDragManager _dragUntilMouseUp:accepted:] + 885
13  AppKit                              0x00007fff8cfdfd8c -[NSCoreDragManager dragImage:fromWindow:at:offset:event:pasteboard:source:slideBack:] + 1455
14  AppKit                              0x00007fff8d2d8cc6 -[NSWindow(NSDrag) dragImage:at:offset:event:pasteboard:source:slideBack:] + 132
15  liblwawt.dylib                      0x00000001175556f2 -[CDragSource doDrag] + 501
16  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9063870d -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 61
17  Foundation                          0x00007fff95e05d70 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 214
18  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff905b74f1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
19  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff905b6d5d __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 253
20  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff905ddb49 __CFRunLoopRun + 905
21  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff905dd486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
22  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff945872bf RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 277
23  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff9458e56d ReceiveNextEventCommon + 355
24  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff9458e3fa BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 62
25  AppKit                              0x00007fff8cc0b779 _DPSNextEvent + 659
26  AppKit                              0x00007fff8cc0b07d -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 135
27  libosxapp.dylib                     0x00000001175e56f4 -[NSApplicationAWT nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 124
28  AppKit                              0x00007fff8cc079b9 -[NSApplication run] + 470
29  libosxapp.dylib                     0x00000001175e5557 +[NSApplicationAWT runAWTLoopWithApp:] + 156
30  liblwawt.dylib                      0x000000011753dba9 -[AWTStarter starter:] + 873
31  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9063870d -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 61
32  Foundation                          0x00007fff95e05d70 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 214
33  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff905b74f1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
34  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff905b6d5d __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 253
35  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff905ddb49 __CFRunLoopRun + 905
36  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff905dd486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
37  java                                0x000000010f3ca3b0 CreateExecutionEnvironment + 871
38  java                                0x000000010f3c4b5c JLI_Launch + 1952
39  java                                0x000000010f3ca70d main + 101
40  java                                0x000000010f3c43b4 start + 52
41  ???                                 0x0000000000000005 0x0 + 5
)
```

Comment: I can reproduce this using the example cited, but only _after_ using a cell editor.